# Increase labeling width of y axis in gnuplot

Tags: canvas, plot, gnuplot

Good morning,

how can i increase the width of the y-tics labels in gnuplot? Or the other way..how can i increase the size of the plot without increasing the complete size?

I've got a `data.csv` like:

```
46,21,1,2,v_64
44,20,2,2,v_65
37,20,3,2,v_69
44,18,4,3,v_70
63,21,5,3,v_46
54,20,6,3,v_47
34,26,7,1,v_26
63,26,8,2,v_25
43,26,9,1,v_22
52,26,10,2,v_23
```

And wanted to plot:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 6,2.5 enhanced color font "Times-Roman,22"

set yrange [0.5:10.5]
set ytics (\
    "xyzuv is easy to use." 1, \
    "The messages of xyzuv were easy to understand." 2, \
    "The coloring scheme helped me to understand the reasoning of other participants." 3, \
    "The ordering of statements presented by xyzuv did make sense to me." 4, \
    "The quality of the arguments was persuasive." 5, \
    "The quality of the argumentation was persuasive." 6, \
    "I like the general idea of xyzuv." 7, \
    "I was satisfied with using xyzuv." 8, \
    "I would use xyzuv again." 9, \
    "I would recommend D-BAS to others." 10) border offset graph 0, 0

set output "general_small.eps"
plot \
    "data.csv" using (6-$1/$2):3 title "Average" with linespoints ls 1,\
    "data.csv" using (6-$4):3 title "Median" with linespoints ls 2
```

Unfortunately the labeling of y-tics is too wide :(

[image: My plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to manually set the left margin of the plot in order to accommodate the text:

```
f = 1.4

W = f*6
H = f*2.5

set terminal postscript eps size W,H enhanced color font "Times-Roman,22"
margin_width = 5.5

set yrange [0.5:10.5]
set ytics (\
    "xyzuv is easy to use." 1, \
    "The messages of xyzuv were easy to understand." 2, \
    "The coloring scheme helped me to understand the reasoning of other participants." 3, \
    "The ordering of statements presented by xyzuv did make sense to me." 4, \
    "The quality of the arguments was persuasive." 5, \
    "The quality of the argumentation was persuasive." 6, \
    "I like the general idea of xyzuv." 7, \
    "I was satisfied with using xyzuv." 8, \
    "I would use xyzuv again." 9, \
    "I would recommend D-BAS to others." 10) border offset graph 0, 0

set datafile separator ","
set output "general_small.eps"

set lmargin at screen (margin_width / W)

plot \
    "data.csv" using (6-$1/$2):3 title "Average" with linespoints ls 1,\
    "data.csv" using (6-$4):3 title "Median" with linespoints ls 2
```

Comment: Uhh..thats nice! Thanks!